# Match and replace all tabs at the beginning of the line with four spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, match

I've read some other questions and answers on the site, but all of them were a little different from what I'm seeking: replace all tabs at the beginning of a string with four spaces.

What I've tried so far:

```
let m = '\t\tsomething\t'
```

Finding tabs isn't hard with `/\t/g`, but this would get tabs that are not at the beginning of a line. So using `m.match(/(\t\W)/)` does the trick for the sample above, resulting in 2 matches.

But when using `m.replace(/(\t\W)/, '    ')`, the expected result would be:

```
        something // 8 spaces (4 for each \t)
```

but I get this instead:

```
    something // 4 spaces for two tabs.
```

Why is this replacing both tabs just one time? And how can I replace every occurrence of `\t` with the desired string?

Comment: Wouldn't adding an extra space inside the quotes fix this problem?

Comment: If you plan to support all browsers, use `m.replace(/^\t+/, function($0) {return $0.replace(/\t/g, '<4 spaces here>');})`

Comment: Not planning on browser support. I'm working on a CLI tool written in TypeScript. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you are replacing both tabs and a non-word character which may not be a tab character necessarily with four spaces. You are not matching each `\t` character separately.

> replace all tabs at the beginning of a string with four spaces

You could use [`y` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky):

```js
console.log(
  "\t\tHello, world!".replace(/\t/gy, '    ')
);
```

or without using `y` modifier (to support ancient browsers) you could go with a little more bit of code:

```js
console.log(
  "\t\tHello, world!\t".replace(/\t|(.+)/gs, function(match, p1) {
      return p1 ? p1 : '    ';
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`^` means "beginning of line", `+` means "one or more times", `m` means "multiline" and `g` means "greedy" (find all occurrences). Finally, there is a little trick to convert one occurrence of n tabs into n dots (I use dots to prove that I don't replace trailing tabs) :

```
YYY = "YYY";
n = YYY.length;
(new Array(n + 1)).join("X") // "XXX"
```

```js
var tabs = document.getElementById("tabs");
var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
var text = tabs.textContent;
dots.textContent = text.replace(/^\t+/mg, function ($0) {
  return (new Array($0.length + 1)).join(".");
});
```

```html
<pre id="tabs">
 1 leading tab, 1 trailing tab 
  2 leading tabs, 1 trailing tab 
   3 leading tabs, 1 trailing tab 
</pre>
<pre id="dots"></pre>
```

Comment: You could reduce array construction and joining costs with `'.'.repeat($0.length)`

Comment: @revo You are right, I'm not used to it, not so long ago it was not compatible with all browsers.